# How do I make sure dynamically generated div is loaded into DOM before js function is called on it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, dom

I'm submitting a form with ajax and opening a Colorbox with the response data:

```
$("#submitB").click(function () {
    $.post("/previewproposal", $("#proposal-form").serialize(), function(data){$.colorbox({html:data});}, "html");
});
```

The rendered html is like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){

        function plotData()
        {
            var dataArray = ...;
            var options = ...;

            $.plot($("#placeholder"), dataArray, options);
        }

        plotData();
    });
</script>

<div id="placeholder" style="float:left;margin:0;font-size:8pt;width:540px;height:180px;"></div>
```

One of the dynamically generated divs is a Flot plot placeholder. I am currently getting the following error:

```
uncaught exception: Invalid dimensions for plot, width = null, height = null
```

The Flot plot function needs the width and height of the plot placeholder div to work. So I'm thinking that my plot placeholder div is not loaded in the DOM at the time the plot function is being bound/called? After much googling and finding questions that are kind of close to this, I couldn't find an example of how to make this work. How do I troubleshoot here? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can't you simply call `plotData()` in your [`$.post`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) success handler? Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

You need to make your ajax synchronous but it is not possible with the wrapper $.post() . So change it to :

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  async:false,
  url: "/previewproposal",
  data: $("#proposal-form").serialize(),
  success: function(data){
         $.colorbox({html:data});
  },
  dataType: 'html'
});

//you can call plotData() here...
```

Comment: You can do this with `$.post`, there is a success callback.

Comment: It's not about callback but about async:true

Comment: edit my post to switch the asynchronous to synchronous, sorry i'm tired:). I also add a comment to say you can call your method after. But in success callback is a better place as saw jrummell